# apache solr search with *

Tags: search, solr

When I search like this: q=*6205* I got much more results then searching q=6205, and it's good
but my problem is:
when I search for q=6205-2RS or q=6205\-2RS I got some results but when I put * in a search string I receive no results (q=*6205-2RS* or q=*6205\-2RS*) Why?

I want to search for *6205-2RS* but I want solr to search this string also in a middle of items names.

Answer (score 1):

Wildcards queries does not undergo any analysis.
So when you are searching for `6205-2RS` with wildcards, it would be searched as is, without any analysis like lower case filter, worddelimiters.

Whats the schema defination for the field. Is it a text field or a String field type ?

The definition for text_general is as below -

```
<fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
    <!-- in this example, we will only use synonyms at query time
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="index_synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="false"/>
    -->
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

The tokenizer and lower case filter in analysis at index time for 6205-2RS would generate tokens 6205,2rs
As no analysis takes place during search, its searching for 6205-2RS as is, and will not find any results.

Change the field type to string and that should match the results.

Comment: type of the field is "text_general"

Comment: thanks for the answer, do I need to reindex whole index after changing type? or just restart apache solr?

Comment: yup changing the fieldtype would need a reindex.